# Call base method from inherited function pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

My base class contains a function pointer to a member function. How can I call this member function from the derived class? I want to call this function by its pointer.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()          {FuncPtr = &Base::Func1;}
    Base(int num)   {
        if(num==1)
            FuncPtr = &Base::Func1;
        else if(num==2)
            FuncPtr = &Base::Func2;
        else
            FuncPtr = NULL;
    }
protected:
    void (Base::*FuncPtr)(float ,float );

    void Func1(float x,float y) { std::cout << "Func1 called\n";}
    void Func2(float x,float y) { std::cout << "Func2 called\n";}
};

class Derived : private Base
{
public:
    Derived()                       {}
    Derived(int num) : Base(num)    {}

    void callBaseFunc1      (float x,float y) { this->Func1     (x,y);} // works
    void callBaseFuncViaPtr (float x,float y) { this->(*FuncPtr)(x,y);} // wrong ...
};

int main()
{
    Derived Test;

    Test.callBaseFunc1      (2.72f,3.14f);  // works
    Test.callBaseFuncViaPtr (2.72f,3.14f);  // syntax error in function declaration...

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, just move the parens:

```
void callBaseFuncViaPtr (float x,float y) { (this->*FuncPtr)(x,y);}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Works now! I've tried so many stupid things but not this :P